# I want to make a list from the outcome of a function using lists as arguments

Tags: python, list, dataframe, regression, multiplication

I'm trying to make a list by using other lists as arguments of a function. However, i can't seem to get the right syntax.
This is my code:

```
f1 = theta0 + theta1*(X1_train) + theta2*(X2_train)+theta3*(X3_train)
```

The expected outcome would be a list of the same length of X1_train, X2_train and X3_train (which is the same for those 3).

I expect to get a list of the outcomes of each element on the lists X1_train, X2_train and X3_train as arguments of the funcion. For example, if my lists were

```
X1_train = [0, 1]
X2_train = [1, 2]
X3_train = [0, 2]
```

I'd expect a list of numbers like

```
f1 = [theta0 + theta2, theta0 + theta1 + theta2 + 2*theta3]
```

The thethas are random numbers.

This lists are columns of a dataframe I converted into lists so I could do the function.

Comment: Could you gives us a hint about your expectations ?

Comment: Yes! I expect to get a list of the outcomes of each element on the lists X1_train, X2_train and X3_train as arguments of the funcion. For example, if my lists where
X1_train=[0,1] 
X2_train = [1,2]
X3_train =[0,2]
I'd expect a list of numbers like f1=[theta0+theta2, theta0+theta1+theta2+2*theta3]

Comment: Could you provide a dummy example of such a function ?

Comment: f(x1,x2,x3)=1+2*(x1)+3*(x2)+4*(x3) where x1, x2 and x3 are lists.

Comment: If I understand what you're doing, which is not totally clear from your question, you could achieve what you wanted by *not* converting the dataframe columns to lists. Pandas series do work the way you want; ordinary python lists don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
import random

X1_train = [0,1]
X2_train = [1,2]
X3_train = [0,1]

amnt = 2

theta0 = random.sample(range(1, 10), amnt)
theta1 = random.sample(range(1, 10), amnt)
theta2 = random.sample(range(1, 10), amnt)
theta3 = random.sample(range(1, 10), amnt)

EndValues = []
for i in range(0, len(X1_train)):

f1 = theta0[i] + theta1[i] * X1_train[i] + theta2[i] * X2_train[i] + theta3[i] * X3_train[i]
EndValues.append(f1)

print(EndValues)
```

This returns

```
[3, 6] [5, 1] [2, 5] [7, 8]
[5, 25]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this simple code:

```py
def f(X: tuple, theta: tuple):
   if not isinstance(X, tuple):
      raise TypeError('X must be a tuple')
   if not isinstance(theta, tuple):
      raise TypeError('theta must be a tuple')
   if not X.__len__() == theta.__len__():
      raise ValueError('length of tuples is not equal')
   return sum([np.array(x_)*t_ for x_, t_ in zip(X, theta)])
```

Note it would throw an error if X or Theta are not tuples of the same length.

Example: (should work as is

```py
import numpy as np
X1_train = [0, 1]
X2_train = [1, 2]
X3_train = [0, 2]

theta_1 = 1
theta_2 = 1
theta_3 = 3
```

```py
print(f(
    (X1_train, X2_train, X3_train),
    (theta_1, theta_2, theta_3)
    ))
>>> [1 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to zip the three lists into a list of 3-tuples, unpack the 3-tuple, then multiply each `theta` value by its corresponding element before summing the results.

```
f1 = [theta0 + theta1*x1 + theta2*x2 + theta3*x3
      for x1, x2, x3 in zip(X1_train, X2_train, X3_train)]
```

If you think of `theta0` as being multiple by 1, you can generalize this to

```
from itertools import repeat


f1 = [theta0*x0 + theta1*x1 + theta2*x2 + theta3*x3
      for x0, x1, x2, x3 in zip(repeat(1), X1_train, X2_train, X3_train)]
```

which you can reduce to

```
from operator import mul
thetas = [theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3]
trains = [repeat(1), X1_train, X2_train, X3_train]
f1 = [sum(map(mul, t, thetas)) for t in zip(*trains)]
```

`sum(map(mul, t, thetas))` is just the dot product of `t` and `thetas`.

```
def dotp(x, y):
    return sum(map(mul, x, y))

f1 = [dotp(t, thetas) for t in zip(*trains)]
```